# How to read HTTP custom error string

Tags: java

I'm trying to read custom error message I sent along an HTTP response for a web API project using Java.

Currently, I have this piece of Java code to read Header Response,

```
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

public class URLReader {
   public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        URL oracle = new URL(URL);
        HttpURLConnection connection =(HttpURLConnection)oracle.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.connect();
        System.out.println(connection.getHeaderField(0));
    }
}
```

An output of HTTP response header looks like this (Fiddler):

[image]

How can I get `My Error Message` text using Java?

Comment: To my understanding all you need is to assign a key to the header. like the other ones above yours and you will be able to use the key to retrieve the message.

Answer (score 2):

@Abzal Kalimbetov is wrong about [getErrorStream()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/HttpURLConnection.html#getErrorStream()), which will return an `InputStream` when an exception is raised, indicating [response code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_Error) **>= 400** is received from the server.

**Recap:**

```
InputStream inputStream = null;
try {
    // normal operation
    inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
}
catch(IOException exception)
{
    inputStream = connection.getErrorStream();
    //@TODO you can now extract your custom error message from inputStream.
}
```

Comment: Your approach is not so good, you are trying to get inputstream while you know it is not there when the response code is 400

Comment: Take a look at http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/sun/net/www/protocol/http/HttpURLConnection.java#1833

Comment: Response statue code **>= 400** will be regarded as an exception in Java, not just 404 or 410, though they're of FileNotFoundException type, more specific one.

Answer (score 1):

If the request status is greater than or equal 400, you use getErrorStream() method

```
  if(connection.getResponseCode()>=400){ 
       String myErrorMessage = connection.getErrorStream();
  }
```

Comment: Looking at implementation of HttpUrlConnection, errorStream is being used under this condition : `responseCode >= 400`. 1xx and 3xx status codes `doesn't` represent error states. Only 4xx (client error) or 5xx (server error) does.

Answer (score -1):

You can set a header in your server application which you then can read out very simple like this: ( Servlet usage is needed for this. )

```
private void test(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response) {
HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;

httpServletResponse.addHeader( "myErrorMessage", "this is the message" );
String message = httpServletRequest.getHeader( "myErrorMessage" );
}
```

if you don't have these resources available it is possible to get the message like this:

```
//get all headers
Map<String, List<String>> map = connection.getHeaderFields();
for (Map.Entry<String, List<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() +
                 " ,Value : " + entry.getValue());
}

//get header by 'key'
String server = connection.getHeaderField("Server");
```

Comment: @Downvoter please be so kind and let me know why you downvoted so I can learn from it and improve my future answers and my general understanding of programming. Thanks...